# IP address logs and compare

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make small JavaScript IP record and log program which ask user to input IP address and then it checks whether that IP already exist in the array. If IP exist then it tells the user that IP already exist else it adds the IP into the collection array. I have tried several times but it doesn't work.

```
var collection = [];
var ip = prompt("enter ip", "");
for (var ips in collection){
  if ( ip === collection [ips]){
    console.log(ip);
  }
  else   
  { 
    collection.push(ip);
    console.log(ip)
  }
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a truly terrible problem description.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array with nothing in it.

Then for every item in the array you either:

- Log
- Add the current value to it

Since there aren't any, you'll never do either.

(If there were entries, you'd add the current value multiple times).

---

The way to do this with your current approach is to do the push *after the loop*.

```js
var collection = [];
var ip = prompt("enter ip", "");
var seen = false;
for (var ips in collection) {
  if (ip === collection[ips]) {
    console.log(ip);
    seen = true;
  }
}
if (!seen) {
  collection.push(ip);
  console.log(ip)
}
```

The better approach is to use `indexOf`

```js
var collection = [];
var ip = prompt("enter ip", "");
if (collection.indexOf(ip) === -1) {
  collection.push(ip);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter way to do it:

```
var collection = [];
var ip = prompt("enter ip", "");

if (collection.indexOf(ip) < 0)
    collection.push(ip)
else
    alert('The IP ' + ip + 'exists');
```